# max-width and word-wrap are not working in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

Here is some example which is not working in IE8 ([Fiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/rffuk2pa/6/))
I have the table that should have the `width: 100%` and `<td>` element should have `auto` in accordance to the text length but not more than `300px`

Here is simple css that I tried

**CSS**

```
table td{
  max-width: 300px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

But it doesn't wrap the long word line into new line when it is more than `300px`.
The second way I tried is to add `div` element inside the `td`. It works for the `div` only, but `td` element wasn't changed and is more than `300px`.
Also I have tried to add `table-layout: fixed;` and many other things that I found here, but without success.

Here are 2 screen shots how it look like in FF vs IE8:
**FF**
[image]
**IE8**
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this line to your css as a work-around

```
word-break:break-all;
```

Comment: I tried this but this is not exactly the result I need. `break-all` just breaks all the columns to the same width (which is very small). You can check how it works in Mozilla for example with and without `break-all`. I need to have the same behavior on IE8 as I have on my fiddle for the rest browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Word-wrap is CSS3.

In Windows Internet Explorer 8 use:

```
-ms-word-wrap: break-word;
```

Which is an extension to CSS, and can be used as a synonym for word-wrap in IE8 Standards mode.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531186(v=vs.85).aspx
Reference 2: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp

Comment: This wraps the words but `td` width in not changing, so still the same problem. You can see here the result of using `-ms-` [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rffuk2pa/8/embedded/result/) and probably understand what I meant in my question. (Try it in IE8)

Comment: Can you post a Screen Shot of what you are getting in IE8 vs What you want to get in FF?

Comment: [Mozilla](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19157699/FF.png) VS [IE8 behavior](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19157699/IE8.png)